# How to Filter values in two tables using inner join?

Tags: sql-server

How to filter values in two tables using inner join.

There are two tables Employee and SalaryIncrement:

> [image]

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
EmployeeId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
FullName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
MonthlySalary MONEY NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeId)
)

INSERT INTO Employee (FullName, MonthlySalary) VALUES ('John', 12000.00)
INSERT INTO Employee (FullName, MonthlySalary) VALUES ('Lee', 20000.00)


CREATE TABLE SalaryIncrement
(
SalaryIncrementId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
SalaryIncreaseFrom DATE NOT NULL,
AmountOfSalaryIncrease MONEY NOT NULL,
EmployeeId INT NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY(SalaryIncrementId)
)

INSERT INTO SalaryIncrement (SalaryIncreaseFrom, AmountOfSalaryIncrease, EmployeeId) VALUES ('2012-02-05', 5000.00, 2)
INSERT INTO SalaryIncrement (SalaryIncreaseFrom, AmountOfSalaryIncrease, EmployeeId) VALUES ('2012-02-05', 1000.00, 1)
INSERT INTO SalaryIncrement (SalaryIncreaseFrom, AmountOfSalaryIncrease, EmployeeId) VALUES ('2013-05-05', 2000.00, 1)
INSERT INTO SalaryIncrement (SalaryIncreaseFrom, AmountOfSalaryIncrease, EmployeeId) VALUES ('2013-04-05', 1000.00, 2)
INSERT INTO SalaryIncrement (SalaryIncreaseFrom, AmountOfSalaryIncrease, EmployeeId) VALUES ('2014-08-08', 1500.00, 1)
INSERT INTO SalaryIncrement (SalaryIncreaseFrom, AmountOfSalaryIncrease, EmployeeId) VALUES ('2016-03-01', 500.00, 1)
```

From the above two tables I need to retrieve data like in this image below.

I also Need to display additional two columns `Old Monthly Salary` and `New Monthly Salary` calculated by Amount of Salary increased.

Result:

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is a self JOIN on SalaryIncrement. This will be used to calculate the `SUM` of SalaryIncrease.

#### Query:

```
SELECT s1.SalaryIncrementId, s1.EmployeeId, s1.SalaryIncreaseFrom, s1.AmountOfSalaryIncrease, SUM(s2.AmountOfSalaryIncrease) as OldSalary
FROM @SalaryIncrement s1
INNER JOIN @SalaryIncrement s2 
    ON s1.EmployeeId = s2.EmployeeId AND s1.SalaryIncreaseFrom <= s2.SalaryIncreaseFrom
GROUP BY s1.SalaryIncrementId, s1.EmployeeId, s1.SalaryIncreaseFrom, s1.AmountOfSalaryIncrease
```

Then this query only needs to be `JOIN` to `Employee` and it can do the math between the SUM and the current MonthlySalary (sample [link](https://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/448964/old-salary)).

#### Query:

```
SELECT sal.SalaryIncrementId, sal.SalaryIncreaseFrom, emp.MonthlySalary-sal.OldSalary, sal.AmountOfSalaryIncrease,  emp.MonthlySalary-sal.OldSalary + sal.AmountOfSalaryIncrease
FROM Employee emp
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT s1.SalaryIncrementId, s1.EmployeeId, s1.SalaryIncreaseFrom, s1.AmountOfSalaryIncrease, SUM(s2.AmountOfSalaryIncrease) as OldSalary
    FROM SalaryIncrement s1
    INNER JOIN SalaryIncrement s2 
        ON s1.EmployeeId = s2.EmployeeId AND s1.SalaryIncreaseFrom <= s2.SalaryIncreaseFrom
    GROUP BY s1.SalaryIncrementId, s1.EmployeeId, s1.SalaryIncreaseFrom, s1.AmountOfSalaryIncrease
) as sal
    ON sal.EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeId
ORDER BY sal.EmployeeId, sal.SalaryIncreaseFrom
```

#### Output:

```
SalaryIncrementId   SalaryIncreaseFrom  OldMonthlySalary    AmountOfSalaryIncrease  NewMonthlySalary
2                   2012-02-05          7000,00             1000,00                 8000,00
3                   2013-05-05          8000,00             2000,00                 10000,00
5                   2014-08-08          10000,00            1500,00                 11500,00
6                   2016-03-01          11500,00            500,00                  12000,00
1                   2012-02-05          14000,00            5000,00                 19000,00
4                   2013-04-05          19000,00            1000,00                 20000,00
```